# How to detect if the main app is running from a background agent

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-agents

I'm working on a WP7.5 app where I use a background agent to update tiles in the background (when the app is not running).

**In the OnInvoke method of the agent, is there a way to know if the main app is currently running ?**

I'd like to detect that in order to NOT updating the tiles if the app is running because I already udpate them when the app exits.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only choice is to write use isolated storage to communicate, since it's shared by both agent and application.

Have the main application create a blank file on startup, and delete it when it closes. Your agent can then determine if the application is running by checking the existance of that file.

Comment: Yes I've been thinking about this possibility. I'm wondering if there is a simpler way using an API...

Comment: @Jalfp - Unfortunately, there's not.

Answer (score 2):

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) not only lists unsupported APIs for background agents, but also emphasizes some APIs which you are encouraged to use. Among them is the [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx):

> The Mutex class should be used to synchronize access to resources that
>   are shared between the foreground application and the background
>   agent, such as files in isolated storage.

This should be exactly what you want. Create a named Mutex in your main application and try to open it in the background agent. If this succeeds then your main app is running, otherwise not.